# What RAM configuration should I get for ASUS P7P55D?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

My PC is using Asus P7P55D with 2x2GB DDR3 RAM on the A1 and B1 slot. My idea is to add another ram in the B2 slot only since the A2 was blocked by the fan (for the record I'm not sure if using 3 RAM on 4 slot would be fine or not). What kind of configuration should I go for? I have some idea which I may or may not choose:

1. Get 2 4GB on A1 & B1 then put one of the 2GB on B2 **or** get 3 4GB on A1,B1 & B2 **or** get 2 4GB on A1 & B1.
2. Get 8GB instead. I'm still confused over this one since on the [official site](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55D/specifications/) it said that the max. RAM size is 16GB, but on the [manual](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P7P55D/HelpDesk_Manual/) it said that "You may install 1GB, 2GB and 4GB" and I don't know if something bigger than 4GB would even work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have 4 slots, manual says max 4 GB per slot, that's 16 GB in total. Math checks out. It's possible though that 8 GB sticks are supported (or support was added in later BIOS versions). Try searching the web, maybe someone tried this and reported success.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 3 slots, use 2 or 4; otherwise you'll slow the whole machine down.

As always for this type of question, just use one of the main online retailers as your knowledge base. They do this for a living & guarantee their results.

The 3 main ones are Crucial, Kingston & Corsair, but there are others - search 'ram configurator' to find them.

Or just search 'manufacturer model number ram' eg 'Asus P7P55D ram'
One of the first hits was https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/p7p55d  which tells you that though it can take 16GB in all 4 slots, it seems to only be capable of reading 4GB per slot, so your safest bet is to buy a pair of 4GB sticks & discard the existing RAM.

You could try using one of your existing 2GB sticks in the 3rd slot, & see how much slower it seems to run; make your call based on whether it bothers you [it won't damage anything, just won't interleave the memory.]

Comment: what could possibly happen if i use something bigger than 4gb? would it slow down my computer, break it or the mobo simply use only 4gb?

Comment: It would most likely simply not work - fail to boot at all. If Crucial could sell you 8GB sticks... they would ;)